# How to add the previous value to current value from sensor

Tags: datalogging

```cpp
const byte interruptPin = 4;
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR count();
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Set up our digital pin as an interrupt
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), count, RISING);
}

void loop() {

}

void count() {
  volatile float rainrate = 3;
  volatile float rate;
  volatile float total;

  rate = rainrate * 0.1; 
  Serial.println(rate);
```

Every time it tips, it returns 0.3.  How do I add the previous value(0.3) to a new tip, to make it 0.6, and save it into a variable.

Thanks!

Comment: hello, no it should be like, if it becomes 0.6 from 0.3, the next tip will be 0.9 and so on.

Comment: It may be just me, but I have no idea what you mean by "tip".  Not that it matters, I think you have an effective answer to your question anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Btw, you can make the `volatile` variables global, by putting them above `void Setup`.

To put the total (new) value, use:

```
total += <sensorValue>;
```

where `<sensorValue>` is a call to get the sensorValue (or the value that has the sensor value stored in it), but I cannot see that in your sketch.

```
total += 0.3;
```

is the same as writing:

```
total = total + 0.3;
```

The value right of the '='sign is copied (assigned) to the left part of the '=' sign.

Comment: Hello, its working. but I think there's somethings wrong with my code because it outputs as double value. when I tip my tipping bucket reed switch, it outputs as 0.3, 0.6 then stop, next tip will be 0.9, 1.20.

Comment: An Arduino does not make a difference between double or float. I'm not sure what you mean it stops at 0.6. The variable `total` should be increased every time it is (what you call) 'tipping'.

Comment: @Giddsec I suspect you are suffering from "button bounce" - google "arduino debounce" for help.

Comment: Got it all working, thank you very much! :)

Comment: You're welcome; if it helped you, please upvote the answer, if the answer gave the best response, accept it (by using the check mark next to the question). Success with your project.

Answer (score 0):

Why bother doing that arithmetic at every tip, when you could just count tips, and multiply the count by 0.3 whenever a result is needed?

`tips += 1;                    // each time the bucket tips.`

and

`Serial.println(0.3 * tips);   // each time you want a result`

Comment: Just to add context to this answer: floating point arithmetics can be orders of magnitude slower than integer arithmetics on FPU-less devices (like many Arduinos).